# Python split rows in txt file

Tags: python, regex, split

I have .txt list with many rows in the following format:

```
3AD544532F-272|5SD32332S-F72|5FD2124L-Y21|4WA32332P-A26|6DW3224C-I72
(...)
```

How can I split these numbers by vertical bar | so that I can receive output .txt file with the following items:

```
3AD544532F-272-14

5SD32332S-F72-12

5FD2124L-Y21-41

4WA32332P-A26-17

6DW3224C-I72-41
```

I tried using this script but with no correct result.

```
import sys
output = open("output_list.txt","w")
print("read line and put it into list or array as you like to call it")
list = open("list.txt").read().splitlines() 
for i in list:
        re.compiler()
input()
```

Comment: have a look at `split()`.  Also, you're importing `sys` but using `re` in your script..

Comment: Next time, please make an attempt at finding the solution before asking a question on Stack Overflow. Googling `python split` gives the relevant Python docs as the first hit.

Comment: Use `csv` instead if possible. Split with regex is not a good method to parse CSV like data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string like this `3AD544532F-272|5SD32332S-F72|5FD2124L-Y21|4WA32332P-A26|6DW3224C-I72`

You can split by `|` using `split` built in function

```
line = `3AD544532F-272|5SD32332S-F72|5FD2124L-Y21|4WA32332P-A26|6DW3224C-I72`
your_splitted_line = line.split("|")
>>print your_splitted_line
>>['3AD544532F-27','5SD32332S-F72','5FD2124L-Y21','4WA32332P-A26','6DW3224C-I72']
```

Answer (score 1):

`split()` is indeed the best solution. The alternative using regex is

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "3AD544532F-272|5SD32332S-F72|5FD2124L-Y21|4WA32332P-A26|6DW3224C-I72"

>>> for i in re.split('\|',text):
...     print (i)
... 
3AD544532F-272
5SD32332S-F72
5FD2124L-Y21
4WA32332P-A26
6DW3224C-I72
```